# Set up A- and PTR-records automatically

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

is there a way to make the DNS or DHCP server to set up the A-record and PTR-record for each IP in a subnet? instead of adding one by one?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options depending on your needs.

`bind` can be configure with the $GENERATE directive to fill in a range of entries.  This works well if you only want entries that are IP address related.

Many `dhcp` clients can be configured to register their lease with a DNS server.  This does introduce some security risk, so it is best to use a dedicated subdomain.  You DNS server will also need to have appropriate security restrictions added.

The `dnsmasq` DHCP/DNS server will automatically add DHCP reservations to its DNS data.